# error when updating user password with bcrypt in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, express, authentication, passwords

```js
const {password, value} = body.password;

// compares the old and new password

const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, student.password);
if(!passwordMatch) return res.status(400).json({message:"passwords do not match"})
                        
//hashes the password

const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(value, salt);
student.password = hashedPassword;
```

***am using "save()" to save the document***

below is the error am getting

```json
"error": {
        "errors": {
            "password": {
                "stringValue": "\"{ password: 'abcde', value: '123456' }\"",
                "kind": "string",
                "value": {
                    "password": "abcde",
                    "value": "123456"
                },
                "path": "password",
                "reason": null
            }
        },
        "_message": "Secondary validation failed",
        "message": "Secondary validation failed: password: Cast to string failed for value \"{ password: 'abcde', value: '123456' }\" at path \"password\""
    }
```

any help please? am using node, express and mongodb. Am also using postman for testing. I couldn't wrap my head around on what could be causing this problem.

below is the structure of the input (i.e req.body)

```json
{
    "password": {
        "password": "abcde",
        "value": "123456"
    }
}
```

**where**

- password = old password (i.e password existing in the database)
- value = new password to be changed to

Comment: add your route and schema completely,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that youre getting the students._id from somewhere

```
router.patch("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { password, newPassword } = req.body;
    const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(password, student.password);
    if (!validPass) return res.status(400).json("Invalid Password");

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(newPassword, salt);
    await Student.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: student._id },
      { $set: { password: hashedPassword } },{ useFindAndModify: false }
    );
    res.status(200).send("Password Updated");
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send({ message: err });
  }
});
```

You'd be looking at something like this, let me know if this helps